# Definition of the WGS 84

Tags: coordinate-system

I'm having some trouble getting the following things straight with , does this make sense?

```
EPSG:4326 WGS84
Coordinate system: WGS84
Datum/Ellipsoid: WGS84
Projection: longlat
```

Answer (score 5):

The geographic coordinates systems (also called lat/long) are defined by 3 features : a datum, a prime meridian (most of the time, it is Greenwich) and a unit (most of the time, it is degree). The EPSG code help to unambiguously identify a geographic coordinate sytem (you can find the description on spatial reference.org)

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

WGS 84 is ambiguous because the name of the coordinate system is the same as the name of the datum (this is often the case with geographic coordinate systems), and the datum is identical to the ellipsoid (The WGS 84 Coordinate System origin also serves as the geometric center of the WGS 84 Ellipsoid and the Zaxis serves as the rotational axis of this ellipsoid of revolution, see [here](http://www.oosa.unvienna.org/pdf/icg/2012/template/WGS_84.pdf) )

Finally, I would not call "lat/long" a projection because it provides angular coordinates, while the "true" cartographic projections are projected on a plane with 2D cartesian coordinates (XY). Therefore you could write :

```
Coordinate system standard code: EPSG:4326 
Coordinate system type:  Lat/Long (or geographic)
Coordinate system name: WGS 84
Datum/Ellipsoid: WGS84
```

EDIT : just for making things clear (hopefully), there are three types of reference systems for locating point at the surface of the Earth:

cartesian 2D (aka projection, cartographic coordinates). The surface of the Earth is projected on a surface that can be transformed as a plane (e.g. cylinder, cone, plane) and the coordinates are distances measured on XY axes. This is used for any map because it is "flat".

geographic coordinate (or lat/long) are angular coordinate giving the angle between the perpendicular to the datum and 1) the equatorial plane (latitude) and 2) the plane that is defined by the prime meridian (longitude). The most famous is WGS 84 that is used by the GPS.

cartesian 3D coordinates. distances are measured on a 3D axis centered on the Earth center. This is mainly used for geodesic aplications.

As a final remark, when you display a lat/long CRS on a (flat) screen, a simple projection is applied by default : the Plate carree, also called Equirectangular. In this case, graticule coordinates are expressed in simple Cartesian form. This is not a projection from ellipsoid to planes like the other pojections, but it is a valid 2D cartesian coordinate system (even if its geometric properties are quite poor).

Comment: Thank you very much!
Which projection should I name? The projection part is still confusing :(

Comment: As I said in my remark, EPSG:4326 is NOT a projected coordinate system. So you should not mention any projection.